# Get Dynamics CRM contact parentcustomerid

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to retrieve full name and parent account of contact in Dynamics CRM.
I am using following code:

```
    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(new String[] { "fullname", "parentcustomerid" });
    Entity retrContact = (Entity)orgService.Retrieve("contact", contactID, cols);
    fullName = retrContact.Attributes["fullname"];
    parentAccount = retrContact.Attributes["parentcustomerid"];
    nameStr = fullName.ToString();
    companyStr = parentAccount.ToString();
```

My problem is that companyStr getting "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference" instead of Name value.
parentAccount contains following:

```
    LogicalName "account"   string
    Name    "Microsoft Corp"    string
    RowVersion  null    string
```

How can I get Name string?

Comment: You already have the answer. companyStr is an EntityReference and you can simply use companyStr.Name to get the name.

Comment: companyStr is a string, so .Name doesn't exist there. I wondreing why I can't use parentAccount.Name. I am getting error:           parentAccount.Name error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parentcustomerid` object is an `EntityReference` object which has the name you're looking for.  This code works:

```cs
ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "fullname", "parentcustomerid" });
Entity retrContact = (Entity)orgService.Retrieve("contact", new Guid("{9DF2ACC2-0212-E611-80E4-6C3BE5A83B1C}"), cols);
var parentAccount = (EntityReference)retrContact.Attributes["parentcustomerid"];
var companyStr = parentAccount.Name;
```

Comment: Thank you @Polshgiant. You gave me an idea. Here is final code:     `parentAccountRef = (EntityReference)retrContact.Attributes["parentcustomerid"];  
                    Entity retrAccount = (Entity)orgService.Retrieve("account", parentAccountRef.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
                    companyStr = retrAccount.Attributes["name"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably fetch the parentAccount from server (please refer to [EntityReference.Name Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.name(v=crm.6).aspx)

> This property is not automatically populated unless the EntityReference object has been retrieved from the server.

E.g. you should fetch the data from server using the Id parentcustomerid, somewhat like

```
Entity Account = service.Retrieve(Account.EntityLogicalName, parentAccount.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
```

You can for sure replace `Account.EntityLogicalName` with `"account"` string.